# Is there a way to hide folder contents to ftp users but still allow them to upload?

Tags: ssh, permissions, directory

I have a folder on my cpanel file manager where multiple users upload to via ftp. Inside this folder are 2 additional folders.

Is there any way of hiding the contents of these folders from the ftp users so only an admin or specified user for example administrator can view them? I have tried using the chmod in the file manager but the folder contents still display to the ftp users. I have a script that takes the user's incoming file and then processes it - moving it from one folder to another.

I read somewhere that maybe this could be achieved by changing the folder permissions via ssh and that there was a way to set special access permissions? 
I have been googling for past few days to try and find a solution but so far been unsuccessful.

Does anyone here know if this is possible?

Regards
Mal

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [sf] or [unix.se].

Comment: Hi thanks. I am learning so apologies for getting things wrong from time to time. I shall check those links out.